# How to obtain verbatim text in a footnote?

Tags: footnotes, verbatim, errors

I want to employ a `\verb` command in a footnote. But, when I run `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I want this.\footnote{\verb|But, it does not work!|}

\end{document}
```

I get this:

```
! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.
```

How can I do what I am after? (I know that I could just use `\footnote{\texttt{But, I lose the semantic mark-up.}}`)

Comment: You want to do something that LaTeX doesn't allow you to do. You either (a) go in and mess with the code under the hood to allow you to do it or (b) work around it. For (b), it'd be nice to know what "semantic mark-up" you are after.

Comment: 1) I know that LaTeX doesn't allow it. (a) That is in the question. (b) I'm trying to help seed in the beta.

2) I'm puzzled by your (b). As I understand it `\texttt{}` is formatting mark-up, and `\verb||` is semantic mark-up. (You mark something as `\verb` and leave the formatting of it up to LaTeX and your documentclass.

Comment: `\verb` is absolutely the opposite of semantic markup it is just a low level instruction to the TeX parser to change the lexical analysis of its input (which is why it doesn't work in macro arguments where the input has already been tokenised). It doesn't say anything about what the content means, just that `\ ` and `{}` should be parsed in a different way.

Comment: Somewhat special case of [errors - How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The package [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) supports this. Just put `\VerbatimFootnotes` anywhere after the preamble, and then:

```
We can put verbatim\footnote{\verb+_Yes!_+} text in footnotes.
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comment and [here](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin), this may conflict with some footnote-specific packages, e.g. `footmisc` when used with the `para` option, but there are other alternatives. Quoting two from there:

- The `memoir` class defines its `\footnote` command so that it will accept verbatim in its arguments, without any supporting package.
- With `fancyvrb`, you can `\SaveVerb` something and `\UseVerb` it in a footnote.

There exist also further packages like [`examplep`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/examplep).

Comment: Note, though, that `\VerbatimFootnotes` doesn't play well with some other packages. See the [UK TeX FAQ entry](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin) for discussion and alternatives.

Answer (score 20):

The [`bigfoot` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) allows verbatim material in footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
% only for this example:
\textheight=.5in
\begin{document}

I want this.\footnote{\verb|But, it does not work!&%$|}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. It's the simplest solution to the problem. 

I tried fancyvrb package first, but I might not have understood exactly how to use  \VerbatimFootnotes.

Comment: Sadly bigfoot.sty also conflicts with footmisc.sty, which allows you to have double spaced text and single spaced footnotes.      Here's the example that's used to illustrate how footmisc works, but with the addition of bigfoot.    Is there a way to use both and still get singlespaced footnotes with `\doublespacing`?   `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}`

Comment: @LeoSimon I don't get double spaced footnotes with `bigfoot` alone nor with both `footmisc` and `bigfoot`, neither with or without changing `\footnotelayout`. (I have an up to date TeX Live, updated yesterday…)

Comment: @clemens, thanks I'll try to figure out how to update.

Comment: Having the same problem as the OP, I tried this solution: while it solved my issue, now my not-so-short footnotes spread across multiple pages instead of being localized at the bottom of the page were they are used! Probably this solution requires a little bit of fine tuning.

Answer (score 13):

`! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.`? Yes. sir!

Well, then let’s use it in an environment:

The environment `lrbox{<savebox>}` works similar to `\sbox{<savebox>}{<stuff to save>}` but instead of saving an argument into a savebox it’s the environment’s body that gets saved into a  savebox. That savebox is then used inside the `\footnote` command.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\myVerb
\newenvironment{verbbox}{\lrbox\myVerb}{\endlrbox}
\newcommand*{\verbBox}{\usebox\myVerb}
\begin{document}
I want this.%
\begin{lrbox}\myVerb%
    \verb|You got this! % \ _ { }|%
\end{lrbox}%
\footnote{\usebox\myVerb}%

I defined a custom environment and a custom macro for you.%
\begin{verbbox}\scriptsize\verb|\begin{verbox} \verb!\begin{verbox} Inception?\end{verbox}! \end{verbbox}|\end{verbbox}%
\footnote{Wow?! \verbBox}%
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Related: [lrbox in \newenvironment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49129)

Answer (score 6):

In this approach, the verbatim material is placed in a box prior to entering the footnote, and the box is recalled within the footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\textheight=1in
\begin{document}
I am ready for a footnote.%
\begin{verbbox}[\footnotesize]
\verbatim material
\end{verbbox}
\footnote{See if \theverbbox\ can appear in footnotes.} And we continue\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[`\cprotect`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cprotect/cprotect.pdf#section.1) is straightforward to use and flexible (e.g., see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83894) to a related question which uses the same solution to use `\verb` within section titles as well).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\begin{document}

I want this.\cprotect\footnote{\verb|And, it works!|}

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot (with`\textheight` adjusted as in the other answers to make the screenshot small):

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score 4):

Another plug for the memoir class: its `\verbfootnote` allows for verbatim material.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nohead, paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=7cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% from the memmoir manual (§ 12.1.1):
Below, footnote~\ref{fn1} is a \verb?\footnote? while
footnote~\ref{fn2} is a \verb?\verbfootnote?.

The \verb?\verbfootnote? command should appear%
\footnote{There may be some problems if color is used.\label{fn1}} %
to give identical results as the normal \verb?\footnote?, but it can
include some verbatim text%
\verbfootnote{The \verb?\footnote? macro, like all other macros except
  for \verb?\verbfootnote?, can not contain verbatim text in its
  argument.\label{fn2}} %
in the \meta{text} argument.

\end{document}
```