# Typeset a series of characters with equal distances?

Tags: macros, spacing

for typesetting tables with design of experiments, I have to typeset strings like "+ - + +", - - - +", etc. in a column of a table to represent the so called pattern of the experimental run (sometimes they also contain "a", "A" and "0" (zero)).

However, the width of the "+" and "-" sign are very different in the used font (standard font in KOMA script class scrreprt) and a sequence of 2 or 3 dashes creates one long or very long dash....

So I'm searching for a way to easily typeset e. g. "+ - - - + -" with a little spacing between the characters and (if possible) that several different strings composed of the same number of characters ("+" or "-", "a", "A" and "0") would be aligned with each other, when they are in the same column of a table.

I hope I could make clear what I need, some examples how it shall NOT look are found here:
[image: bad example]
in line 9 it should be "+ - -" and in 10 "- - +", line 5 should be "- - -"

It looks a little better, if I insert `\,` between the characters, but as the widths are different, it is still not aligned:
[image]

Sure, I could split it up in centered columns like `- & + & - & - & ...`, but the tables are already complicated enough and I do not want to add 3 to 7 columns...

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that?
Maybe a command that parses the string like --+--++ and typesets it with a "constant spacing"?

------- edit:

added math mode for "+" and "-", looks better now, but not perfect:
[image: math mode for plus and minus]

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper%,  halfparskip
    ]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage{booktabs}

    \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\midrule
         1 &        $+$$+$$-$           \\
         2 &        $+$$-$$+$           \\
         3 &        $-$$+$$+$           \\
         4 &        000                 \\
         5 &        $-$$-$$-$           \\
         6 &        000                 \\
\midrule
         7 &        $-$$+$$-$           \\
         8 &        000                 \\
         9 &        $+$$-$$-$           \\
        10 &        $-$$-$$+$           \\
        11 &        $+$$+$$+$           \\
        12 &        000                 \\ 
\midrule
        13 &        000                 \\
        14 &        00a                 \\
        15 &        00A                 \\
        16 &        0A0                 \\
        17 &        A00                 \\
        18 &        0a0                 \\
        19 &        a00                 \\
        20 &        000                 \\
\toprule
\end{tabular}  

\end{document}
```

---

example and further question about side-effects:

I used the solution of Michel and it looks good, but there is one thing I'm not sure about:
Is it possible that it changes the free space between columns?
I have the impression that the first 3 columns are closer together than the rest...
How can I fix that?

[image: solution with side effects?!]

Comment: `\texttt{++----++}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newlength{\stretchlen}\setlength{\stretchlen}{1em}
\def\splitterm{\_}
\newcommand{\stretchit}[1]{\leavevmode\realstretch#1\_}
\def\realstretch#1{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\splitterm
    \else
    \hbox to \stretchlen{\hss#1\hss}\expandafter\realstretch
\fi}
\stretchit{abcd}\par
\stretchit{----}\par
\stretchit{++++}\par
\stretchit{-+-+}\par
\stretchit{0aA+}\par
\end{document}
```

`\stretchit` appends an underscore to its argument and passes it to `\realstretch`, which recursively 'eats' one letter at a time, and typesets it centered in an `\hbox` stretched to `\stretchlen`. All letters are thus equally wide, and since they are centered, aligned nicely.

--- **solution for the question:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newlength{\stretchlen}\setlength{\stretchlen}{1em}
\def\splitterm{\_}
\newcommand{\stretchit}[1]{\leavevmode\realstretch#1\_}
\def\realstretch#1{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\splitterm
    \else
    \hbox to \stretchlen{\hss#1\hss}\expandafter\realstretch
\fi}

without the stretchit command

\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\midrule
         1 &        ++-             \\
         2 &        +-+             \\
         3 &        -++             \\
         4 &        000                  \\
         5 &        ---                 \\
         6 &       000               \\
\midrule
         7 &        -+-                 \\
         8 &       000                \\
         9 &        +--                 \\
        10 &        --+             \\
        11 &        +++             \\
        12 &        000             \\ 
\midrule
        13 &        000                  \\
        14 &        00a                   \\
        15 &        00A                   \\
        16 &        0A0                 \\
        17 &        A00                   \\
        18 &        0a0                  \\
        19 &        a00                  \\
        20 &        000                  \\
\toprule
\end{tabular}  

\medskip

\emph{with} the stretchit command

\begin{tabular}{c>{\collectcell\stretchit}c<{\endcollectcell}ccccccc}
\midrule
         1 &        ++-             \\
         2 &        +-+             \\
         3 &        -++             \\
         4 &        000                  \\
         5 &        ---                 \\
         6 &       000               \\
\midrule
         7 &        -+-                 \\
         8 &       000                \\
         9 &        +--                 \\
        10 &        --+             \\
        11 &        +++             \\
        12 &        000             \\ 
\midrule
        13 &        000                  \\
        14 &        00a                   \\
        15 &        00A                   \\
        16 &        0A0                 \\
        17 &        A00                   \\
        18 &        0a0                  \\
        19 &        a00                  \\
        20 &        000                  \\
\toprule
\end{tabular}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Michel: that's it, thank you! Last question: how can I apply that to a whole table column?

Comment: @Martin: You can use the `collcell` package to apply the `\stretchit` macro to every cell.

Comment: I tried `>{\stretchit\bgroup}c<{\egroup}`, but that gives really weird results. Why doens't it work?

Comment: @Michel: Because macros don't work with implicit braces. Use the `collcell` package and write `>{\collectcell\stretchit}c<{\endcollectcell}`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll have a look and see why that /does/ work. But, something like `>{\realstretch}c<{\_}` also behaves oddly. Must be my lack of understanding of the inner workings of tabular ;)

Comment: @Michel: There is a `\ignorespace` and `\unskip` added by the `tabular` after or before the `>` and `<` code, respectively. They are then also read by your macro. You could change it to remove the `\ignorespace` first and simply use `\unskip` instead of `\_` as an end-marker. However, this doesn't work in the last column of the `tabular` because the ``\\`` is handled differently than `&`. This all was the reason why I wrote `collcell`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, @Michel: thank you very much - with the collcell package it works like expected!

Comment: @Martin Scharrer, @Michel: is it possible that there are side effects influencing the spacing between columns (see my added example http://i.imgur.com/25OVA.png in the question above).

Comment: @Martin: I don't see any side effects? Looks good to me. The only thing I can think of is that the 2nd column is optically not really centered, that's due to the different width of the headers of the 1st and 3rd column. Edit: oh, in the question you detailed the side effect ... hard to tell, there might indeed be a difference in spacing. This might be due to collcell, maybe the other Martin can have a look?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you typeset them it **math-mode**, i.e. `$-$` and `$+$`.

Be aware that it makes a difference if you use a single math-mode or separate ones for them. The last sign has different spacing in the first case because it 
is taken as an unary sign but the others are operators.

Compare the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$-$$-$$-$$+$$+$$+$

$+$$+$$+$$+$$+$$+$

$-$$-$$-$$-$$-$$-$

$---+++$

$++++++$

$------$

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

---

For the alignment with the other signs `a`, `A` and `0` I would recommend that you make macros for all and set the width manually the one of the widest (should be `$+$`).

This can be done either with `\hbox to <length>{\hss <sign>\hss}` (TeX) or using `\makebox[<length>][c]{<sign>}` (LaTeX). The width is provided by `\settowidth{<length register>}{<content>}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\slength}
\settowidth{\slength}{$+$}
\newcommand*{\Sz}{\makebox[\slength][c]{0}}
\newcommand*{\SA}{\makebox[\slength][c]{A}}
\newcommand*{\Sa}{\makebox[\slength][c]{a}}
\newcommand*{\Sp}{\makebox[\slength][c]{$+$}}
\newcommand*{\Sm}{\makebox[\slength][c]{$-$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
         1 &  \Sp\Sp\Sm  \\
         2 &  \Sp\Sm\Sp  \\
         3 &  \Sm\Sp\Sp  \\
         4 &  \Sz\Sz\Sz  \\
         5 &  \Sm\Sm\Sm  \\
         6 &  \Sz\Sz\Sz  \\
\midrule
         7 &  \Sm\Sp\Sm  \\
         8 &  \Sz\Sz\Sz  \\
         9 &  \Sp\Sm\Sm  \\
        10 &  \Sm\Sm\Sp  \\
        11 &  \Sp\Sp\Sp  \\
        12 &  \Sz\Sz\Sz  \\
\midrule
        13 &  \Sz\Sz\Sz  \\
        14 &  \Sz\Sz\Sa  \\
        15 &  \Sz\Sz\SA  \\
        16 &  \Sz\SA\Sz  \\
        17 &  \SA\Sz\Sz  \\
        18 &  \Sz\Sa\Sz  \\
        19 &  \Sa\Sz\Sz  \\
        20 &  \Sz\Sz\Sz  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Looking at the table, I think this is better than my suggestion...

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I don't understand your point about the "unary sign", but I see that in the last 3 rows of your example the block with the last 2 "columns" has a little more space on its left side..

Comment: TeX handles `-y` differently than `x-y`: In the first case the minus is an unary oparator (affects only one variable) in the second a binary operator. This affects the spacing. You get the correct spacing for the last symbol in the bottoms examples if you use a brace pair: `$---+++{}$` and so makes it a binary symbol.

Comment: @ Martin Scharrer: What about inserting "0", "a" and "A" - that makes problems in pure math mode... :-(

Comment: @Martin: You only need to put the `-` and `+` signs into math-mode. Like `$-$0a`. Maybe define some macros like `\P` for `$+$` and `\M` for `$-$`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: that's ok for "+" and "-", but what about the a's and Zeros? they don't have the same spacing (see the minimal example I've added)

Comment: @Martin: Ok, now I get it. You can set them manually to have the same width. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: thanks for your update. Michel's solution (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14576/typeset-a-series-of-and-with-eqal-distances/14582#14582) seems a little more flexible.

Comment: @Martin: Ok, I didn't saw Michel's solution before I updated my question. Both use similar underlying code, just Michel's boxes the characters automatically.

Comment: If you're using macros like this, then my original texttt solution might prove the simplest way of achieving this...

Comment: @Seamus: Yes, simply using `tt` font would also give you constant-width characters for all used signs. However, I don't think that the font would look good in that given table.

Answer (score 3):

one possible form to typeset your table would be to use a table column for each character:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\Pl{${}+{}$}
\newcommand\Mi{${}-{}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc@{\hspace{-2pt}}c@{\hspace{-2pt}}c}
  \toprule
  1 & \Pl & \Pl & \Mi \\
  4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 12 & a & 0 & A \\
 15 & 0 & 0 & A \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that's right. However, as I said: "the tables are already complicated enough and I do not want to add 3 to 7 columns..."

Answer (score 3):

Michel's solution is nice, but I'd like to present some improvements.

```
\newlength{\stretchlen}
\settowidth{\stretchlen}{+}
\newcommand{\stretchit}[1]{\realstretch#1\_}
\newcommand\realstretch[1]{%
  \ifx#1\_%
  \else
    \makebox[\stretchlen]{\ifx#1-$-$\else#1\fi}%
    %\hbox to \stretchlen{\hss\ifx#1-$-$\else#1\fi\hss}%
    \expandafter\realstretch
  \fi}
```

It's not necessary to have `\splitterm` and to define `\temp` at each stage, since we're collecting tokens one by one and those tokens are simple characters. It's best also to set `\stretchlen` to the widest character, in this case `+`. Finally, there's the particular case of `-` that should be treated differently with a `$-$`.

I've left commented the line with `\hbox`: with `\makebox` it's more in the LaTeX way of thinking; the two lines give the same result, but of course `\makebox` is a bit less efficient than `\hbox`.

---

Some years later, the solution can be made more robust, with the possibility of managing other characters that need special treatment.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\stretchit}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \makebox[\stretchlen]
     {
      \str_case:nnF { ##1 }
       {
        {-}{$-$}
        {+}{$+$}
        {*}{$*$}
       }
       {##1}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\stretchlen}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\stretchlen}{$-$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r >{\collectcell\stretchit}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\midrule
 1 & ++- \\
 2 & +-+ \\
 3 & -++ \\
 4 & 000 \\
 5 & --- \\
 6 & 000 \\
\midrule
 7 & -+- \\
 8 & -*x \\
 9 & +-- \\
10 & --+ \\
11 & +++ \\
12 & 000 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to achieve this would be to typeset the plusses and minuses in a monospace font with `\verb|+-+-|`

There are however [issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203/215) with verbatim text which you might run into...
Another solution might be to use `\texttt` and macros for your plusses etc. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\p{+}
\newcommand\m{-{}}
\begin{document}
\texttt{++---++}

\texttt{\p\p\m\m\m\p\p}

\texttt{++\m\m aA0}
\end{document}
```

You need to use a macro like this for the minus sign because otherwise they get turned into en-dashes if you use the `fontenc` package. This should also mono-space letters easily.

Comment: The problem with `--` and `---` is that it will be converted to a dash, even with `tt` font. The `\verb` should avoid that because it disables ligatures, but has the usual issues of verbatim commands.

Comment: @Martin I didn't notice this because `tt` font only turns `--` into a dash if you use `fontenc` which wasn't in my testing environment

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing to `fontenc`. I wasn't aware of that relationship.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution might be to enclose the symbols in braces: `${-}{+}{+}{+}$` looks better than `$-+++$`, as LaTeX won't try to interpret each `+` or `-` as a binary operator.