# Verbatim environment inside footnote

Tags: footnotes, verbatim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to obtain verbatim text in a footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203/how-to-obtain-verbatim-text-in-a-footnote)

I would like to have a verbatim environment inside a footnote.  The following does not work.

```
main text sentence\footnote{Consider
\begin{verbatim}
something
\end{verbatim}
} continuation of main text sentence.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: At least related question: [Verbatim inside a command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83893/verbatim-inside-a-command). Also, the [`bigfoot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) package allows verbatim material in footnotes.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate because currently, the question looks very similar to [How to obtain verbatim text in a footnote?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203/how-to-obtain-verbatim-text-in-a-footnote). Note that closing a question is not final. If you feel that this question is not a duplicate you can edit it to add more information, in which case it may be reopened. And before I forget: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I must have overlooked the question you mention.  Yes, it is what I was asking.  Thanks much.