# Using multiple { and }

Tags: soul

It seems that using multiple `{{{` and `}}}` causes some problem to the latex document. Assume this line

```
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
   something \hl{I am referring to \cite{publi}} is good.
\end{document}
```

But I get this error

```
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.180 ...something \hl{I am referring to \cite{publi}}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: There is a distinction between some commands --- some are fragile, some are robust.  I believe this problem might be arising from the same veins as [putting verbatim content into a footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `\cite` inside an `\mbox`, as suggested in the [`soul`](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf) under **Protecting** (p 4):

```
\hl{I am referring to \mbox{\cite{publi}}}
```

As a further reference, see [How to make `\hl` (highlighting) to automatically place incompatible commands in `\mbox`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139463/5764)