# Include a footnote in verbatim text

Tags: listings, footnotes, verbatim

I have seen how to add verbatim text to a footnote: [How to obtain verbatim text in a footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203)

What I would like to do is the opposite, include a footnote in a `verbatim` section. I am using the `memoir` class, `listings` for verbatim sections, and `perpage` footnotes. The footnote should appear at the bottom of the page just as a regular footnote would. I don't mind if the footnote symbol/superscript (not sure of technical term) is texttt vs the normal style.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`listings` provides the possibility to escape to LaTeX inside a listing, see section 5.12 *Escaping to LaTeX* of the manual for details. The basic idea is to set an *escapechar* which switches to LateX and back:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,gobble=2,escapechar=ß]
  helloß\footnote{test}ß world
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Instead of `escapechar=<tokens>` which sets one or more characters `<tokens>` for starting and ending the escape you can also use `escapeinside={<tokens1>}{<tokens2>}` or `escapebegin=<tokens1>,escapeend=<tokens2>` if you want two different characters/strings `<tokens1>` and `<tokens2>` for begin and end. `<tokens1>` and `<tokens2>` also can be the same tokenlist. (Tests suggest that if `<tokens>` is longer than one token it cannot only contain the same token – I haven't determined a definite pattern behind this behaviour, though, and the manual doesn't seem to say anything about it.)

Comment: Use the parameter texcl of the package listing, for example \begin{lstlisting}[texcl] ... Then you can use footnotes after comment sign, e.g. "SELECT ?city ?cityLabel WHERE { # \footnote{test}" for SPARQL script. The symbol # is the SPARQL comment sign.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version without the use of packages (i.e., works in plain `verbatim` environment).  I make `?` (or any char of your choosing) active and employ `!` (or any char of your choosing) as a delimiter.

With this syntax, `?!My footnote!` is the equivalent of `\footnote{My footnote}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight=1.5in\relax% FOR THIS MWE ONLY
\begin{document}
{\catcode`?=\active
\def?!#1!{\footnote{#1}}
\begin{verbatim}
This is a?!My footnote! test, and another?!another footnote!;
And now for some more?!yet another footnote! here.
Finally, the last one?!final footnote! here.
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `verbatim` package to define a new environment that defines a character to enclose the footnote text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\textheight=3cm % just not to waste space

\newcommand{\vfchar}[1]{%
  % the usual trick for using a "variable" active character
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1 \lowercase{\endgroup\def~##1~}{%
    % separate the footnote mark from the footnote text
    % so the footnote mark will occupy the same space as
    % any other character
    \makebox[0.5em][l]{\footnotemark}%
    \footnotetext{##1}%
  }%
  \catcode`#1=\active
}
\newenvironment{fverbatim}[1]
 {\verbatim\vfchar{#1}}
 {\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{fverbatim}{?}
Some verbatim and a footnote?Text of the footnote? here
Another?Text? and let's see the alignment
is good enough
\end{fverbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]