# How to obtain verbatim text in a footnotetext?

Tags: errors, footnotes, verbatim

I want to use a `\verb` command in a `\footnotetext` in `pdfLatex`, like:

```
\footnotetext{Some text \verb|some\_text|}
```

But, I encounter:

```
 ! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions proffered at [How to obtain verbatim text in a footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203/how-to-obtain-verbatim-text-in-a-footnote?rq=1) Is there a particular reason that you're calling `\footnotetext` directly? If so, some of these may not work, but using `fancyvrb` and its `\SaveVerb`/`\UseVerb` facility may give you what you need. See the [documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/doc/fancyvrb-doc.pdf) for more details.

Comment: I have tested the documentation example: `\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\SaveVerb{Verb}|_verbatim_|
text \UseVerb{Verb}`. But, I throw errors!

Comment: Did you add `\usepackage{fancyvrb}` to your document preamble? What errors are you getting?